# Meaning of "A man has as many masters as he has vices."

Tags: proverbs, phrase-meaning

What does this saying mean? It was said by Augustine of Hippo, but I do not exactly understand it. Thanks.

> A man has as many masters as he has vices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He's paraphrasing his Boss:

John 8:34

> Everyone who commits sin is a slave of sin.

Comment: pithy and eloquent.

Answer (score 13):

It means your vices control you; they are your masters.

While you may think you are your own master, or that you serve one master, in reality, the things you are addicted to control your behavior, and, therefore, you.

Answer (score -1):

A person’s tendencies to carry out acts of immoral or unethical practices are the invisible rulers.